# Is there a word for a person who is able to focus on multiple tasks at same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

I thought of the word 'multi-tasker' but is there a better word which can express focussing on multiple tasks with equal efficiency? For instance, it is said that Leonardo Da Vinci, a polymath, was able to write and draw at the same time.

Comment: I believe "polymath" simply refers to a Renaissance man, or someone who knows a lot about a variety of subjects, not necessarily a "multi-tasker.":)

Comment: *Multipotent* and *versatile* come to mind, but none of them has the connotation of "at the same time".

Comment: I'm not sure how writing and drawing at the same time would work. Are we talking two pieces of paper, write a word on one, turn to the other, add a bit of foliage, turn back to the first and write a sentence, turn around and add some shading... ? Or it supposed to be some sort of extreme form of ambidextrousness?

Comment: I've never really believed that there was such a person--one who can multi-task with equal efficiency--though I have no doubt there are a lot of people who *think* they can.

Comment: @Martha - it's the latter option.  Drawing with one hand while writing with the other.

Comment: @bikeboy389 I'll have you know that I can breathe and surf the internet simultaneously without losing any efficiency. In fact, I would go so far as to say breathing actually improves my surfing ability longterm. I can even bite my nails without thinking about it! :p

Comment: @Murali. The phrasing is misleading: because when you focus on something, it is at the expense of the rest. Unless you can have a human equivalent of an ellipsoid (which has 2 focal points whereas a circle has only one).

Comment: A.D.D. ... oh sorry you said same time.  I got distracted halfway through. :D

Answer (score 2):

There must be a word, however it doesn't make sense. A person, as many studies and research suggest, is only capable to  concentrate on one task at a time.

I found some interesting information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_multitasking

Comment: But rapid switching is probably is what we call 'multi-tasking' when referring to people.

Comment: As per the definition of "concentrate" I guess ;-)

Comment: @jgbelacqua: And computers... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_%28computing%29

Comment: A plate juggler can easily keep multiple separate plates spinning in the air at the same time. Is this multitasking? I think most people would say yes. You could argue that the entire process of spinning all the plates is a single task, so she's not multitasking, but you could also argue that each plate is a separate task. You could even argue that each eye, each finger, each muscle is performing a separate tasks, but that's getting silly.

Answer (score 2):

Multi-tasker is probably the most widely recognized English phrase for this. Someone able to do remarkable feats of intellect or creativity, like Leonardo writing and drawing at the same time, is often called a prodigy. That doesn't necessarily imply doing multiple things at once, but it's the sort of thing that a prodigy might be able to do.

Answer (score 2):

"*Multi-tasker*" is probably the most recognized descriptor.  But in reality, one is time slicing and diverting attention from one task to another in bursts.  It's perhaps noteworthy that a study of college students found that most were overall less effective when "*multi-tasking*" than when they focused their attention for longer blocks of time.  Unfortunately, the students also underestimated the detrimental effect of shifting focus too often.

It actually makes some rational sense because the older pejorative descriptor of attempting this used to known as "*scatterbrained!*"

Comment: This is the same answer as one given only a few hours ago.